# C# web api generic response for success status

Tags: c#

How to create generic response in WEB API2 instead always writing

```
return Ok(new { success = true });
```

So I am doing this and then in angular checking if reponse.success === 'true'

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(MyModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _helper.Create(model);
            }

            return Ok(new { success = true });
        }
```

Comment: Why isn't just returning an empty OK enough to satisfy a success?  You can return other codes if it isn't a success.

Comment: how do you mean empty OK? Problem is that i need to check reponse in angular

Comment: Just `return Ok()`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. You want to create a generic class that contains your status of the response? In this case you can create a class for generic purpose.

```
public class Response
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is success.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is success; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The error message.
    /// </value>
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And after that you can use like this:

```
 return Ok<Response>(new Response { ErrorMessage = "", IsSuccess = true });
```

Or you can use just the Ok response without any parameter and check the status code of the request on your angular app:

```
return Ok();
```

Angular part:

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    })}).then(function successCallback(response) {
         //If it's Ok -> 200 HTTP
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      //If error occured -> 500 HTTP etc.
  });
```

Comment: The first option is what OP's asking to avoid doing constantly. The second option is more in line with what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you return `Ok()` from your API, what actually gets sent is an [HTTP Status Code 200](https://httpstatuses.com/200). That is used by Angular's AJAX functions to determine whether to call your `success` or `error` functions. There are [many other status codes that can be sent](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), however not all have direct Web API 2 classes to encapsulate them.

Returning only `Ok()` would be enough to tell your application that it succeeded. You will want to include other information (your object) if there are multiple things that could happen during the call. For example, since your action method is called `Add()`, one of the things you might want to return is the ID of the object you just created, but if you don't need to, you don't have to.

What you should do is to not return anything in the body, and if you hit your `success` Angular function, then it succeeded. If something happened during the call, an OK/200 response will not be returned, and your `error` will be called instead.